# Is stopping a single photon possible?

Tags: visible-light, photons, speed-of-light

I'm curious if it's possible to use some kind of "magnetic confinement" to essentially suspend a single photon?

[image: suspended_photon]

Comment: Depends what you mean by stopping, but I think yes: (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsphotonics.9b00314)

Comment: also it depends of how you define "photon", i.e. which field theory . In the QFT of elementry particle physics the photon has zero mass thus always velocity c, axiomatically.

Comment: I assume you mean suspending a photon while maintaining its energy/frequency? Otherwise every photon is eventually stopped when it impacts a mass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking if a photon could be "stopped"$^1$ in the traditional sense of "stopping", is not a well-defined question.

There exits no frame of reference where a photon can be considered stationary. And a photon has no charge, nor does it have a magnetic (or electric) dipole moment, and so it cannot be affected by a magnetic (or electric) field. So magnetic (or electric) confinement does not appear to be feasible.

Since a photon is massless it must travel at the speed of light, and this speed is invariant regardless of the motion of the source or observer.

Confining a photon to a small region in space is perhaps the closest one can get to achieving this, although the photon still moves at the speed of light in between collisions of the walls in this region.

This was achieved for individual photons by Nobel prize winner [Serge Haroche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serge_Haroche).

In essence, this was done using what's called a *high Q cavity* that is essentially a box who's inside walls are reflecting mirrors. This cavity was able to store one photon for about $20ms$.

$^1$Unless it is completely absorbed at a point, at which point it ceases to be a photon anyway.

Comment: Joseph, your point about  photon cannot be affected by a magnetic  field lead me to a doubt and I aks abot [Deflection of a photon from a structured magnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/646377/deflection-of-a-photon-from-a-structured-magnetic-field)

Comment: Hello Holger. If you are suggesting that a photon can be deflected using a magnetic field because it has a magnetic moment, then this is not true. A photon certainly does not have a magnetic dipole moment (nor does it have charge).

Comment: I agree with you that a photon has neither a charge nor is it a magnet. Does this mean that it has no oscillating fields? The photon leaves a polariser with the orientation of what?

Comment: Hello Holger. No. _Individual_ photons interacting as point particles do not behave as oscillating E and B fields. Only a confluence of many many photons will have this _classical_ structure which is described by _classical_ electrodynamics. Cheers.